# EffectComposer and alpha channel with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here is my code :

```
renderTargetParametersRGBA = { 
minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
 format: THREE.RGBAFormat,stencilBuffer: true 
 };
colorTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(
 SCALE * SCREEN_WIDTH, SCALE * SCREEN_HEIGHT, renderTargetParametersRGBA
 );
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( 
renderer,colorTarget 
);
var renderScene = new THREE.RenderPass(scene,camera);
var effect2 = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.ShaderExtras[ "shader1" ]);
composer.addPass(renderScene);
composer.addPass(effect2);
```

In renderScene I set the alpha channel of my scene to a certain value but in my shader1 I don't find the same value for the alpha channel, it seems that the alpha channel is destroyed.What's wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really "transparency" in Three.js EffectComposer layers (which are textures). Transparent pixels are simply rendered black (0,0,0) or the background color by default, so when you combine pixel values in your shaders, do the math to account for those "transparent" values in such a way that they produce the color combinations you'd expect if it were transparent.

There is also a way to directly control the alpha in the shader if you pass in the value as a uniform or attribute (depending on your goal). For me, I pass in a separate attribute array of alpha values and then use them to control alphas in the shader itself.

```
varying float vAlpha;
varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {
gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor, vAlpha );
...
```